# Why aren't my registered users showing on the Django admin panel?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am relatively new to django. I am developing a user registration system. I have tried testing the user registration but the details aren't getting shown in the admin panel.I can manually add someone form the backend but when they use the form, and submit, it doesn't show in the admin panel for users and I don't get any errors.

I have tried checking for the method in the form, I also tried changing the html method from "post" to "POST" but it didn't work and any errors in views or urls but can't seem to find where I am wrong.

This is my views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from userauths.forms import UserRegisterForm
# Create your views here.
def register(request):
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
        
    context = {
        'form':form,
    }
    return render(request, "userauths/register.html", context)
```

This is my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from userauths.models import User


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
   
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']
```

Here is my html form

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

Comment: So what happens if you submit?

Comment: The page just refreshes,  and the form returns back, nothing shows on the admin panel

Comment: What does the console print? Are you sure you make a POST request (normally the request is logged in the console).

Comment: Can you please share your logs, and console output. Does your registration form include "password" field? Is there any error raised in console?

Comment: Maybe your form is invalid and since you have not put an if block for what happens when the form is invalid, you are unable to see any errors. 
Put a print statement inside the `if form.is_valid():` and see if it prints. If not, it means that your form is invalid, in that case, try putting a print statement in an else block to check what exactly is your form's errors

Answer (score 1):

You are using `from userauths.models import User` not `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` which is the default user.

If you want to have your own user model, you have to add it to the admin panel described below.

Go to your `admin.py` and add the following code.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import # Your Model here


admin.site.register(Your Model)
```